# Save 96 images in temp file Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i actually need to save 96 images in the temp file Iphone.
Indeed i have a slider with 96 values and for each value 
i have differents images, if i want to do that, this is to have 
a movie with the 96 images who scroll when i move the slider .

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be best of storing them in [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

The reason for this would be easier animation (later on, if needed) since the [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) also holds a property named `images` of `NSArray` type.

There are many examples of how to read/write arrays to file. For example: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html

Edit: if all your images are known at compile time then you should simply name them frame_0.png to frame_95.png. Load them into `NSArray` at application launch and use the images simply as:

`(UIImage *)[array objectAtIndex: x]`